# Varnish trabalhando apenas com Curl

Tags: php, laravel-5, cache, nginx

Bom dia, este é meu cenário, estou utilizando laravel 5.3 e Varnish 5, criei uma middleware que passa uma response com os seguintes Headers

```
X-Cacheable:1
Cache-Control:max-age=300, public
```

No Varnish vcl em vcl_backend_response

```
if (beresp.http.X-Cacheable ~ "1") {
   unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
```

Com o comando `um curl -I <ip>`,

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.13.5 Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8 Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public X-Cacheable: 1 Date:
>   Sat, 09 Sep 2017 11:54:40 GMT X-Varnish: 24 8 Age: 24 Via: 1.1 varnish
>   (Varnish/5.0) X-Cache: HIT X-Cache-Hits: 15 Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   Connection: keep-alive

Mas nos navegadores, ele não cacheia.
Alguém pode me dar uma luz?